# Iterar sobre arreglo de strings y extraer los que comiencen con vocales

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, split

Tengo un array con nombres y apellidos, y debo iterar sobre el mismo para extraer los que comiencen el nombre o apellido con una vocal.
Establecí una variable con las vocales y dentro de un ciclo for aplicando un if. Pero no me dio resultado. Si pueden ayudarme por donde atacar primero el problema seria de gran ayuda.

```js
let actoresVocales = [];
let actoresPrincipales = [
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Johnny Depp",
  "Elizabeth Taylor",
  "Morgan Freeman",
  "Jennifer Aniston",
  "Meryl Streep",
  "Natalie Portman",
  "Ashton Kutcher",
];
let nombreYapellido=actoresPrincipales.join(" ")
let nombresYapellidos=nombreYapellido.split(" ")

for(let i=0; i<actoresPrincipales.length;i++){
  let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  if(nombresYapellidos[i][0]==vocales[i]){
    actoresVocales.push(actoresPrincipales[i])
}
```

Comment: Aquí el problema es que al iterar los la i toma el valor del número por lo que en vocales será el mismo es decir si ```i=1``` entonces el nombre en la posición 1 se evaluará con la vocal en la posición 1, más no recorres el arreglo de las vocales, puedes solucionarlo con otro ciclo for o con el método ```includes()``` de js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comentarios en el código.

```js
let actoresVocales = [];
let actoresPrincipales = [
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Johnny Depp",
  "Elizabeth Taylor",
  "Morgan Freeman",
  "Jennifer Aniston",
  "Meryl Streep",
  "Natalie Portman",
  "Ashton Kutcher",
];
let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

actoresPrincipales.forEach(actor => {
// arreglo para almacenar por separado el nombre y el apellido
let nombreApellido = actor.split(' ')

// tomar la primera posición del nombre y del apellido,
// convertirla a minúscula y comprobar si existe en el arreglo
// de vocales
if(vocales.includes(nombreApellido[0][0].toLowerCase())
|| vocales.includes(nombreApellido[1][0].toLowerCase())
)
  actoresVocales.push(actor)
  
})

console.log(actoresVocales);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has aclarado cierta cosa de los || con tu respuesta. Sinceramente, debería ser la respuesta marcada

Answer (score 2):

Debes utilizar bucles anidados. En este caso, dentro de cada iteracion " **i** " del array `actoresPrincipales` debes recorrer el array `vocales` y comparar cada vocal con la primer letra del nombre y apellido de `actoresPrincipales[i]`

```js
let actoresVocales = [];
let actoresPrincipales = [
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Johnny Depp",
  "Elizabeth Taylor",
  "Morgan Freeman",
  "Jennifer Aniston",
  "Meryl Streep",
  "Natalie Portman",
  "Ashton Kutcher",
];

let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

for(let i = 0; i < actoresPrincipales.length; i++){

  //Conviertes el string a minusculas y despues lo separas por nombre y apellido
  let nombreYapellido = actoresPrincipales[i].toLowerCase().split(" ")
  
  let nombre = nombreYapellido[0]
  let apellido = nombreYapellido[1]
 
 //Comparas cada vocal con la primer letra del nombre y del apellido
  for(let j = 0; j < vocales.length; j++){
    if(nombre.charAt(0) == vocales[j] || apellido.charAt(0) == vocales[j]){
      actoresVocales.push(actoresPrincipales[i])
    } 
  }
}
```

Notese que para extraer la primer letra de cada string utilizé la función `charAt()`

Answer (score 0):

Agradezco las respuestas de todos. Gracias a los aportes pude llegar a una solucion del problema de la siguiente forma. Comparto el codigo. Slds.

```js
let actoresVocales = [];
let actoresPrincipales = [
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Johnny Depp",
  "Elizabeth Taylor",
  "Morgan Freeman",
  "Jennifer Aniston",
  "Meryl Streep",
  "Natalie Portman",
  "Ashton Kutcher",
];
let vocales = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
for (let i = 0; i < actoresPrincipales.length; i++) {
  let actores = actoresPrincipales[i].toLowerCase().split(" ");
  let nombre = actores[0];
  let apellido = actores[1];
  if (vocales.includes(nombre[0]) || vocales.includes(apellido[0])) {
    actoresVocales.push(actoresPrincipales[i]);
  }
}
console.log(actoresVocales);
```